# Element wise operation on nested numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Background

I have a nested numpy array and I want to:

1. First, add a different random value to each **scaler element** of nested numpy array
2. And then, delete the value larger than 10.

...

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]] 
#(add random value for each scaler element)
[5.5, 6.7, 8.2], [4.1, -3.0], [**16**, -2, 7]] 
# (remove elements larger than 10)
[5.5, 6.7, 8.2], [4.1, -3.0], [-2, 7]]
```

Code:

```
original_nested_array = np.array([np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,2,1])], dtype = object)

# add a random value on each minimum element of original_nested_array
...
# Delete elements larger than fixed value, e.g. 10
...
```

The point is that my nested array has elements with different length.

In the example above, the first element has length == 3, second has length == 2, third has length == 3. Thus, `original_nested_array.shape` equals to `(3,)` instead of `(3,3)`, which is harder for elementwise or broadcasting operation.

Comment: I tried to clean up the formatting, but I'm not sure I got it right.  And I can't figure out what you are trying to do.  With an array like this, you have to handle each nested array separately, in a loop or list comprehension.  Think of this as a list of arrays, not a 'nested array'.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I want. I can do it within a loop. Just want a automatic numpy solution since `original_nested_array` is completely a numpy array object

Comment: What do you mean by "minimum" element? it looks like you re adding to every value

Comment: The nested array in my example has two layers, each one's type is numpy array. The minimum element means scalar element.

Comment: Numpy functions work on numpy arrays, which are saved in memory as a contiguous block of data. This data object you called "nested numpy array" does not have a contiguous representation in memory, so it cannot be handled by efficient numpy operations, such as broadcasting. Jérôme Richard's answer explains this well.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the length of each parts, compute the offset of each sections (number of item preceding the current item in a flatten representation), merge the parts with `np.concatenate`, add random number using a simple sum with `np.random.randn`, find the location of the maximum with `np.argmax`, delete the element of the flatten array and update the the section offsets before splitting the array with `np.split`:

```py
len_of_parts = np.fromiter(map(len, original_nested_array), dtype=int)
part_sections = len_of_parts.cumsum()
all_values = np.concatenate(original_nested_array).astype(np.float64)
all_values += np.random.randn(all_values.size)
max_index = all_values.argmax()
all_values = np.delete(all_values, max_index)
part_sections[np.searchsorted(part_sections, max_index, 'right'):] -= 1
output = np.split(all_values, part_sections[:-1])
```

However, please **do not use jagged array**! They are clearly not efficient. Numpy is not design to manipulate them efficiently nor easily. In fact, the overhead of Numpy function is mostly multiplied by the number of items in the jagged array. Thus, a jagged array of 1000 items containing subitems of an average size of 10 can be up to 1000 time slower to compute than one big flatten array (it is about 200 times slower on my machine in this case). In fact, using Python list is likely much faster in such a case (but still inefficient compared to a big array).

The efficient solution is to **flatten jagged array and keep an array of start-end sections** defining sub-arrays. This is especially much faster if you use Cython or Numba to compute operations that can be hardly done with Numpy.

Also note that delete operations are slow since a now array needs to be created (and almost copied). This is fine to use `np.delete` as long as it is not done in a loop (at least not a critical one). Otherwise, the complexity can become much worse with this call.

Comment: To add to this answer: see [Compressed Sparse Row (CSR)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) representation of sparse matrices in scipy. This is a clear example of holding a flattened data (`data`) representation with an array of start-end sections (`indptr`), assuming `indices` is an array of 1's. Scipy has many built-in methods for this type of matrices. Could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from typing import Union

class NPTools:
    def __init__(self, nparray:Union[np.array, np.ndarray, list,tuple]):
        if isinstance(nparray, (list,tuple)):
            nparray = np.array(nparray)
        self.nparray = nparray

    def bb_get_size_of_biggest_element_in_list(self, lst: iter):
        return len(max(lst, key=len))

    def aa_adjust_2d_numpy_array(self, fillvalue=np.nan, dtype=np.object_):
        maxlen = self.bb_get_size_of_biggest_element_in_list(self.nparray)
        ajustedlists = np.array(
            [
                *(
                    np.fromiter(x + (maxlen - len(x)) * [fillvalue], dtype=dtype)
                    for x in self.nparray
                )
            ]
        )
        self.nparray = ajustedlists
        return self

    def aa_sort_2d_numpy_array(self):
        self.nparray = np.array([np.sort(lst) for lst in self.nparray])
        return self

    def bb_create_random_value_array_of_same_shape_with_int(
        self, startvalue: int, stopvalue: int
    ) -> np.array:
        return np.random.randint(startvalue, stopvalue, self.nparray.shape)

    def bb_create_zero_array_of_same_shape(self) -> np.array:
        return np.zeros(self.nparray.shape)

    def bb_slice_vertical(
        self, start_index: int = 0, stop_index: Union[int, None] = None
    ) ->np.array:
        """[[2 2 3]
             [4 5 nan]
             [6 7 8]] -> [2 4 6]
        bb_slice_vertical(1,2)
        second_part = sorted_array[0:,1:2]
        rest : bb_slice_vertical = bb_slice_vertical[0:,1:]

        """
        if stop_index is None:
            return self.nparray[0:, start_index:]
        return self.nparray[0:, start_index:stop_index]

    def bb_delete_all_na_in_2d_array(self):
        return np.fromiter(
            map(
                lambda arraya: np.array([x for x in arraya if pd.notna(x)]),
                self.nparray,
            ),
            dtype=self.nparray.dtype,
        )

    def aa_apply_vetor_function(self, function, arguments=None):
        if arguments is not None:
            applyfunction = partial(function, *arguments)
        else:
            applyfunction = partial(function)

        oct_array = np.frompyfunc(applyfunction, 1, 1)
        self.nparray = oct_array(self.nparray)
        return self

    def aa_sort_array(self):
        self.nparray = np.sort(self.nparray)
        return self

    @staticmethod
    def cc_delete_elements_if_smaller(comparevalue:Union[int,float], value:Union[int,float]) ->Union[int,float]:
        if pd.isna(value):
            return np.nan
        if value < comparevalue:
            return np.nan
        return value

    @staticmethod
    def cc_delete_elements_if_bigger(comparevalue:Union[int,float], value:Union[int,float])->Union[int,float]:
        if pd.isna(value):
            return np.nan
        if value > comparevalue:
            return np.nan
        return value

randomlist = [
    [3, 2, 2], [4, 5], [6, 8, 7] ]

nptools_ = NPTools(np.array(randomlist))

vertical_slice = (nptools_.aa_adjust_2d_numpy_array(fillvalue=np.nan, dtype=np.object_) #ajust_array, so that all lists have the same length
                  .aa_sort_2d_numpy_array() #sort_all_arrays, so that the smallest element's index is 0 in all lists/arrays
                  .bb_slice_vertical(start_index= 0, stop_index=1)) # get_all_minimum values

print(f'{nptools_.nparray=}\n')

print(f'{vertical_slice=}\n')

vertical_slice += np.random.randint(0,10,vertical_slice.shape) # add some random numbers to the smallest number in each list

print(f'{nptools_.nparray=}\n')

nptools_.aa_apply_vetor_function(function=NPTools.cc_delete_elements_if_bigger, arguments=[10]) #return np.nan if the number is bigger than 10

print(f'{nptools_.nparray=}\n')

finalarray = nptools_.bb_delete_all_na_in_2d_array() #get rid of all np.nans, so that only the values bigger than 10 are left over

print(f'{finalarray=}\n')


output:

nptools_.nparray=array([[2, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, nan],
       [6, 7, 8]], dtype=object)
vertical_slice=array([[2],
       [4],
       [6]], dtype=object)
nptools_.nparray=array([[10, 2, 3],
       [11, 5, nan],
       [13, 7, 8]], dtype=object)
nptools_.nparray=array([[10, 2, 3],
       [nan, 5, nan],
       [nan, 7, 8]], dtype=object)
finalarray=array([array([10,  2,  3]), array([5]), array([7, 8])], dtype=object)
```